# Is there an infinite number of finite termed polynomials passing through an infinite number of points?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I already know that this statement is true for finite points, but it got me thinking about infinite points.

Take, for example, $\sum_{i=1}^n i$, the sum of the natural numbers. An equivalent finite termed polynomial for this is given by $\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$, which works for an infinite number of points of the summation function.

My question then, is this: are there an *infinite* number of *finite* polynomials that pass through *any* infinite set of points, **for instance** as the finite formula for the sum of the natural numbers, passing through an infinite number of points from the summation?

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have not worked out a proof yet , but I think the polynomial fitting infinite many points (if existent) is always unique.

Comment: Hint: if two polynomials pass through the same infinite set of points, then the difference of those two polynomials has infinitely many zeros.